# netuseradd user already exists error

Tags: c++, windows-7, createuser

I receive user already exists error code when I try to create account programmaticaly in windows 7, although user does not exists. What may be the cause of this problem ?

```
int wmain(int argc, wchar_t *argv[])
{
USER_INFO_1 ui;
ui.usri1_name =L"test-PC";
ui.usri1_password = L"12";
ui.usri1_priv = USER_PRIV_USER;
ui.usri1_home_dir = NULL;
ui.usri1_comment = NULL;
ui.usri1_flags = UF_SCRIPT;
ui.usri1_script_path = NULL;

addUser(NULL, ui);

while(true){}
return 0;
```

}

```
int addUser(LPWSTR servername, USER_INFO_1 ui) {
DWORD dwLevel = 1;
DWORD dwError = 0;

// Call the NetUserAdd function, specifying level 1.
NET_API_STATUS nStatus = NetUserAdd(servername, dwLevel, (LPBYTE)&ui, &dwError);

// If the call succeeds, inform the user.
// Nerr_Success error code is 0 independant from nerr_base
if (nStatus == NERR_Success) {
    fwprintf(stderr, L"ADD: User %s has been successfully added on %s\n", "1", "2");
    return 1;
}
//Nerr_base should be given since userexists is calculated by adding nerr_base to error code
else if((NERR_BASE + nStatus) == NERR_UserExists) 
    fprintf(stderr, "ADD: Account already exists: %d\n", nStatus);
else if(NERR_BASE + nStatus == ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED)
    fprintf(stderr, "ADD: Access Denied: %d\n", nStatus);
else if(NERR_BASE + nStatus == NERR_PasswordTooShort)
    fprintf(stderr, "ADD: Password is too short: %d\n", nStatus);
else if(NERR_BASE + nStatus == NERR_PasswordTooLong)
    fprintf(stderr, "ADD: Password is too long: %d\n", nStatus);
else
    fprintf(stderr, "ADD: A system error has occurred2: %d\n", nStatus);

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Why do you specify `dwLevel` equal to zero? It shall be equal to 1.

Comment: Thank you for your response I realized that lately.It solves my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dwLevel` parameter cannot be zero, it shall be in range 1-4, according to [`NetUserAdd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370649%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) MSDN documentation.

Comment: Even successfully added user, I could not see new user under user accounts. I want to login with the account created with code written above. In a question one suggests adding account into groups needed. I have done that also but it does not work for me. What could be the problem ?

Comment: See this http://forums.codeguru.com/archive/index.php/t-379648.html. Hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks useful link.After I have added user under "administrators" group, It works. 
To check whether accounts created succesfully or not "local users and groups" can be checked as in the link.
http://www.installsetupconfig.com/win32programming/networkmanagementapis16_30.html